# How to read password protected excel input in pentaho?

Tags: excel, input, pentaho, password-protection, pentaho-spoon

How to read data from a password protected excel sheet in pentaho excel input step?
If we cant read data from password protected excel sheet, how can we skip the file and read only password less excel sheets in pentaho?

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDI cannot read Excel files that are password protected to open.

See here:

- http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?56662-Excel-Input-with-password-protected-workbook
- http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-10939

The Excel step does not have a failed handler, so you cannot to this inside the transformation. You can however have a job call a transformation, and this transformation step in the job will fail if the Excel file fails. I would have a job that would call the Excel transformation for each file, and then have a failed and success handler in the job.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
is there any way to skip the password protected file and read other files ?

Comment: I have a large number of excel files(number can change for every run) in input directory. How can excel input will read the password less files and skip protected files ?

Comment: As I said in the answer. Iterate over them and execute a job, that will execute a transformation for every XLS.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can we implement the iteration over a excel file? Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: For instance: Have a transformation that runs Get File Names, and then run a ExcelRunner job. Then have the job run the transformation that reads the excel file.